# google cloud sql соединение. работают только SELECT. INSERT не работает

Tags: mysql, google-cloud

Старый legacy PHP код,
соединение

```php
$this->cid = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $name);
$this->db_name = $name;
```

Соответственно - могу через него получить любую выборку Google Cloud SQL
но не могу добавить запись

Локальный MySQL работает штатно

Использовать сокеты? `mysql_err.log` пустой в журналах

Comment: из cloud console запросы INSERT выполняются

Comment: Что значит "но не могу добавить локальный"? Опишите в вопросе подробнее